# .desktop file for ncurses application

Tags: terminal, ncurses, .desktop

I am trying to create a .desktop file for the calcurse ncurses calendar application:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=calcurse 
Comment=an ncurses calendar
TryExec=calcurse
Exec=lxterminal -e calcurse
Terminal=true
```

Problem: The only thing that happens when I click the menu entry is that I am presented with an empty terminal, no calcurse anywhere. Having `Exec=calcurse` produces the same result.

Issuing `lxterminal -e calcurse` from within a terminal does launch a new terminal window with the calcurse application running as expected.

How should I configure my .desktop file for it to launch the ncurses application instead of just an empty terminal?

Comment: I think you should simply have "Exec=calcurse". The "Terminal=true" line instructs whoever handles this .desktop file to launch it within your preferred terminal emulator.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! Tried it but it did not work. Have updated my question.

Comment: Could you please also state which graphical environment (e.g. Gnome Shell, Unity, KDE, ...) are you using?

Comment: What happens if you replace `calcurse` with `yes`? Do you get a terminal with `y` repeating endlessly? If so then the terminal tries to start up `calcurse` (the .desktop file infrastructure is working as expected), and it might be something not properly initialized for `calcurse` to run. My first guess would be the TERM variable, try having `Exec=env TERM=xterm calcurse` (yes, all this as a single line) and see if it works.

Comment: Having any of `Exec=calcurse`, `Exec=yes` or `Exec=env TERM=xterm calcurse` produce an empty lxterminal window. Issuing `env | grep TERM` produces `TERM=xterm`, both from xterm and lxterminal

Comment: I am running LXDE on Lubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is nothing wrong with the .desktop file. Hence there must have been something wrong with my setup of Lubuntu. After switching to a clean install of Devuan everything works as expected.